# Update TextView in fragment's parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, textview

I just need to modify the parent's TextView from its Child fragment. The activity is actually still showing alongside the fragment so I assume I should be able to modify it from the fragment but I have been met with an NPE so far with everything I have tried. I see some posts on updating fragments from their parent, but I need to do the opposite, and those functions have not worked thus far.

I have put this method inside of my MainActivity(the parent) to allow updating of the TextView from the fragment.

```
 public void updateGoldTextView(int goldAmount) {
    goldTV.setText(String.valueOf(goldAmount));
}
```

In my fragment I am calling the method as so:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.updateGoldTextView(50);
```

What do I need to do in my fragment to allow me to reference this properly?

Comment: How are you trying to call this method from your code with is throwing a NPE?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I meant to post that. Will update in 2 seconds!

Comment: But the NPE is coming from my MainActivity, when I try to set the text. As if I no longer have access to that TextView(Even though it's still currently showing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the method wrong! Try the following in your fragment.

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).updateGoldTextView(50);
```

To understand how this works, every `Activity` in Android is a screen that the user sees. Your `MainActivity` hosts the fragment. To access the parent activity from your fragment, you are supposed to use the `getActivity()` method.

Comment: You're exactly right. So you are getting the activity, which is cast to (MainActivity)?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Basically to get the parent activity you are supposed to use `getActivity()` and not create a new instance of the `MainActivity` which you are currently doing!

Comment: In fact, you should never create an instance of an `Activity` like you did above ever.

Comment: This method should be used any time you want to reference an activity's values or methods? Never create instances like I had done?

Comment: Yes. You should never do that! Because in Android, each `Activity` is nothing but the screen that is visible to the user. You go from one activity to another using intents. You do not create activity instances like you created.

Comment: I have done that thus far without any issues! I will keep that in mind in the future and try to avoid it. Thanks for the quick assistance! @Antrromet

Comment: @KevinHodges Happy coding!!

Comment: I wish it would allow me to do that immediately without having to wait! Done! Thanks again!

Comment: It'll soon! Once you gain enough reputation :)

Comment: What if it's vice versa? I am getting NPE error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 0):

But the best practice to pass data from fragment to activity is you should use interface.so that at any point you won't get NPE.